# What happens to my Google Play Music library when I unsubscribe?

Tags: google-play-music, paid-apps

I'm currently shopping for a music streaming service because I'm currently unsatisfied with Spotify, my current service of choice.

Lured in by the three month free trial, I'm enjoying Google Play Music for a series of reasons, but now that I finally moved my library of music from Spotify to GPM, I'm curious about what will happen if I ever decide to unsubscribe.

Will GPM delete all the songs I added? Or, should I ever want to renew my subscription, will I find them all where I "left" them? I know I won't be able to play the songs while on the free level, obviously, but what I'm wondering is if Google will keep all the songs and albums I added, tied to my Google account or, what I'm afraid of, deletes everything forcing me to readd everything once I decide to pay again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [What happens when you cancel your subscription](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/3122088?hl=en) from Google support page says (emphasis added)

> When the end of the billing period is over and your subscription is canceled, **you won't be able to access music you downloaded to your device, or playlists you created.**
>
> If **you subscribe again, you'll get access** to your radio stations and also the playlists and music you uploaded.

- [What happens to All Access albums in my library when I unsubscribe from Google All Access?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/48818/what-happens-to-all-access-albums-in-my-library-when-i-unsubscribe-from-google-a) reiterates
- [If you unsubscribe from Google Play Music All Access and then re-subscribe you will not have the ability to play YouTube videos in the background on Android](https://m.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/33b7nl/psa_if_you_unsubscribe_from_google_play_music_all/) another setback for some users

Comment: Thanks, I searched but couldn't find anything!

Comment: I can verify that this answer is correct through experience. Even playlist access through the web-page is shutdown.  Cancelling your paid subscription won't just result in adds being played thereafter... ALL your playlists go bye-bye because... evil reasons?